# Spring interceptor vs servlet filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

What advantages does a Spring interceptor have over a servlet filter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring HandlerInterceptor vs Filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000844/spring-handlerinterceptor-vs-filters)

Comment: @skaffman: Having looked at it now I agree, but the answer here is clearer and more concise.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- You can inject other beans in the interceptor
- You can use more advanced mapping patterns (ant-style)
- You have the target handler object (controller) available, as well as the result `ModelAndView`
- It is a bean, so you can use AOP with it (althoug that would be rare)

Comment: You can inject other beans into a Filter if you use a DelegatingFilterProxy.

Comment: true. With that filter your filters are regular beans

Comment: can you make the interceptor fire for all controllers?

Comment: so you just add your interceptor to the list for a SimpleUrlHandlerMapping, you don't need to have the mappings xml section?

Comment: Is it possible for it to be excluded for certain paths, like for static resources?  say exclude all urls that begin with /images/

Comment: that's no good, because now my interceptor is firing for each image that is loading (I want the interceptor to run for every controller, I don't want to list all the controllers for the interceptor to run).

Comment: as soon as you immediately return from the interceptor in case of an image, it is not a big overhead.

Comment: unless their are 10 images per page.  but anyway, images shouldn't be served by tomcat anyhow....but for development it is annoying to see so many log messages go by...

Comment: Another advantage of Interceptors is that there are 3 opportunities to act: 1) before controller, 2) after controller / before view, and 3) after view. A Servlet Filter only has before & after.