# Which of the two - Servlet Filters or AOP - is better to implement Security?

Tags: java, servlets, aop, servlet-filters

I am trying to implement security in my Spring web application that only those users who have purchased the application will only use the application 
and not the others. Apart from that I also need to make sure that the user will use the web app only between a specific time frame for which he 
has paid for.

**EDIT 1**

At present I am thinking of servlet filters to use and intercept the requests to access my pages. As each request is intercepted by the container itself I have full control over my resources. I can also make sure that the pages are served during the fixed duration as I have access to `FilterConfig` and hence Servlet Context.

I also know about AOP method interception. In case of AOP the controller method calls interception is done by spring container but not the application server. Does this have any limitations over using Filters? Any ideas or suggestions? Or what other standards exist for tasks like this?

Comment: May be this will give you an idea  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942317/spring-interceptor-vs-servlet-filter

Comment: @rangalo Thank you. But my question is between the two mentioned which is better as I have to access context object and are there any better alternatives of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would just say that two most knowned security frameworks use filters. And before implementing your solution, you might have a look at them.

- [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org) said to be more simple at first glance
- [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security) said to be more feature rich