# How can I check for a presence of a logged in user in a session using JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, jstl, servlet-filters

I want to check if the user is logged in or not using JSTL.

I tried the following code:

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.logged_in == null}">
      <c:redirect url="index.jsp"></c:redirect>
</c:if>
```

I have also tried the following code but it throws an `IllegalStateException`:

```
<c:if test="${empty user}">
    <b>you are not logged in</b>
<c:redirect url="index.jsp"></c:redirect>
</c:if>
```

but it is not working.

How can I implement the following code in JSTL:

```
<%
   String logged_in = (String) session.getAttribute("logged_in");
   if (logged_in == null) {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
   }
%>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info

Comment: The @BalusC suggested variant (see the example in his link) is the more preferred solution. It is the common practice to use servlet filters for the things like a login check. But of course it's up to you ...

Comment: @informatik01 The question is about JSTL but not about filters.

Comment: @Alexey Yes, I agree that you gave the answer for the question he asked in the last sentence. But the **preferred and most common** way of checking if user is logged in or not is by using servlet filters. I just gave him a hint, you know

Comment: @informatik01 In this case it can be some interceptor (spring mvc) for example because we don't know anything about backend for this question.

Comment: @Alexey Maybe, although no mentioning of Spring was seen in the question. btw interesting answer here as well: [Spring HandlerInterceptor vs Servlet Filters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8006367/814702). Again, as I understand, BalucS just gave him a link to help him see the direction to move for. And I agreed with that. No worries )

Comment: Indeed. The OP is using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and I liked the concept of filters :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`<c:if test="${empty logged_in}">`
`<c:redirect url="index.jsp"></c:redirect>`
`</c:if>`