# Where to write authorization in spring boot? In spring interceptor or filter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, authorization

I am currently developing an application with micro service architecture using OAuth as authentication in Spring Boot. Since my authorization server is a separate micro service, I cant use spring's annotation based role based authorization for my resources in resource server. Therefore I am writing custom implementation to check the role and its access before reaching the resource. I have two choices, either to do it in interceptor or in a Filter.
Which is best suited for this authorization?

Comment: Why are you writing a custom implementation? Separating the authorization server and resource server is the whole point of OAuth, and Spring Security OAuth2 provides out-of-the-box support for either opaque tokens or JWT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion one of the biggest difference between Filters and Interceptors is:

Filter works only in J2EE web applications, you can not use outside of the application servers, Interceptors can work in different components and not depends on the web layer, in summary interceptor have a wide field than filters. If you are planning to move some component outside the container, you should consider use interceptors.

Filters work more in the request/response domain, in the other hand interceptor act more in the method execution domain.

**If you need to do something that could affect the request or response to your application such as logging, security, audit, or you will affect the data coming on them, your option is filter, don't forget the plug ability that those provides.**

ref:[Interceptors Or Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381648/interceptors-or-filters)