# Start and end of web request lifecycle in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, events, lifecycle

I'd like to track & print some diagnostic information (when in debug run) for when a web request starts and when it ends. Is there some kind of event/listener/callback I can register to listen for web request lifecycle events?

To make it more concrete, one of the things (not the only one) I want to do is track how long it took to process the request.

Comment: Tomcat? http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter

Comment: I also want access to the objects in my Spring environment, such as the Hibernate SessionFactory. In addition, I debug with Jetty, not Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Tomcat as your server, you can try its Request Dumper Filter:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter

Otherwise, you could try a HandlerInterceptor in Spring [Spring HandlerInterceptor vs Servlet Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000844/spring-handlerinterceptor-vs-servlet-filters/8006367#8006367)